# Passing a PHP variable back to ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

```
if($rx==$_SESSION['randomx'] and $ry==$_SESSION['randomy']){
    echo "Cestitam, zadeli ste pravilno celico! rabili ste samo:".$_SESSION['poskus'];
}
    else{
    $razdalija=sqrt(($rx-$_SESSION['randomx'])*($rx-$_SESSION['randomx'])+($ry-$_SESSION['randomy'])*($ry-$_SESSION['randomy']));
    echo $_SESSION["poskus"].". Zgresili ste za: ".round($razdalija);
    $_SESSION["poskus"]++;
}
```

Both echos return a sentense how can i differenciete those two sentences?
In the ajax function i want to compare which one came back so i can set the background color.

Comment: Instead of returning a string, return structured data like JSON or XML containing meta data on which peace of data was returned.

Answer (score 1):

I would return json instead and use the key to differentiate between the possible outputs.

For example:

```
$arr = array();
if ($rx==$_SESSION['randomx'] and $ry==$_SESSION['randomy']) {
    $arr['good'] = "Cestitam, zadeli ste pravilno celico! rabili ste samo:".$_SESSION['poskus'];
} else {
    $razdalija=sqrt(($rx-$_SESSION['randomx'])*($rx-$_SESSION['randomx'])+($ry-$_SESSION['randomy'])*($ry-$_SESSION['randomy']));
    $arr['bad'] = $_SESSION["poskus"].". Zgresili ste za: ".round($razdalija);
    $_SESSION["poskus"]++;
}
echo json_encode($arr);
```

Now you can check in javascript which one is set and do what you want to do.

You could also return an additional value that determines the status and a text value for the text, plenty of possibilities. The key is sending back structured data instead of just a text string.

Comment: And then i can use if(data=='bad') and so on?

Comment: @user3617642 Not directly, if the json is parsed, you'd use something like `if ('bad' in data)` or `if (data.hasOwnProperty('bad'))`. And then you use `data.bad` or `data.good` which contains the text.

Comment: The numbers are undefined, i must be doing something wrong.

Comment: @user3617642 What numbers and is the json parsed? You'd need to ask a new question or post the ajax function to get help with this specific problem.